# Two properties of the same name under same schema. Error when trying to retrieve value of property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to recursively run through the Json file and retrieve a property named "fileName", and then add the value of that property to a ListView. However, the problem is that, as the title says, there are two instances of the same property in the same schema, which is what I believe is causing the error.

I want to ignore the "fileName" property that contains "spigot.jar", and only retrieve the property that contains "spigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".

Sample of the Json I am trying to parse (or use http://ci.md-5.net/job/Spigot/api/json?depth=1 as reference):

```
"artifacts" : [
    {
      "displayPath" : "spigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar",
      "fileName" : "spigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar",
      "relativePath" : "Spigot-Server/target/spigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    },
    {
      "displayPath" : "spigot.jar",
      "fileName" : "spigot.jar",
      "relativePath" : "Spigot-Server/target/spigot.jar"
    }
  ]
```

How I am trying to parse, and add it to a ListView in C#:

```
var url = "http://ci.md-5.net/job/Spigot/api/json?depth=1";
var content = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);

dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

foreach (var builds in json.builds)
{
    string fileName = builds.artifacts.fileName;

    lvServers.Items.Add(fileName);
}
```

How should I go about retrieving the "fileName" property successfully?

Comment: your code works awesome but why do we need to use dynamic  word ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following.  This will list out the build number plus the first filename for each build:

```
var url = "http://ci.md-5.net/job/Spigot/api/json?depth=1";
var content = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);

JObject root = JObject.Parse(content);

var list = root["builds"].Select(b => 
           b["number"].ToString() + " - " + 
           b["artifacts"].Select(a => a["fileName"].ToString())
                         .FirstOrDefault());

foreach (var fileName in list)
{
    lvServers.Items.Add(fileName);
}
```

**Demo**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/54l8YX

Note that build #1603 has no artifacts (I'm guessing because the result was FAILURE for that build) so the filename is empty.

---

**Explanation of what's going on in the above code**

I'm using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects, JTokens, JArrays, etc.) combined with built-in .NET extension methods from the [System.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.100).aspx) namespace ([`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx), [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx)) and a couple of [*lambda expressions*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to extract data from the JSON hierarchy.

Here's how it breaks down:

1. I first parse the downloaded content into a `JObject` using `JObject.Parse(content)`.
2. With a `JObject`, I can use square-bracket syntax (like one would for a `Dictionary`) to get the value of an immediate child property within that object.  `root["builds"]` gives me a `JArray` of `JObjects` representing the list of builds.
3. The `Select` method allows me to take an [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) of something (in this case the `JArray` of `JObjects` representing the builds), iterate over that list and apply a function to each item in the list in order to transform it into a list of something else (in this case a list of strings).
4. The function I am applying to each build `JObject` is a [*lambda expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx): `b => b["number"] + " - " + b["artifacts"] ...`.  In this expression I am saying "from a build `b`, get the `number` property as a string, concatenate it with a separator `-` and a sub-expression which gets the first filename from the list of artifacts for the build.
5. In the sub-expression, I get the value of the `artifacts` property of the build (which is another `JArray` of `JObjects`), then use `Select` on that to transform it into a list of filenames with the lambda expression `a => a[fileName].ToString()`.  But, since I only want the first fileName, I use `FirstOrDefault()` to cull the list to a single item (or null if there are no items).

Hopefully that makes some sense.  If you're not familiar with LINQ or lambda expressions, then the code is going to seem a little cryptic for sure.  Below is an alternate version which does not use these constructs, but does exactly the same thing.  It might be a little easier to understand.

```
var url = "http://ci.md-5.net/job/Spigot/api/json?depth=1";
var content = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);

JObject root = JObject.Parse(content);

foreach (JObject build in root["builds"])
{
    string buildName = build["number"].ToString() + " - ";

    foreach (JObject artifact in build["artifacts"])
    {
        JToken fileName = artifact["fileName"];
        if (fileName != null)
        {
            buildName += fileName.ToString();   
        }
        break;
    }

    lvServers.Items.Add(buildName);
}
```

**Demo**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vwebrY

Comment: I like this approach much better now that I understand more of what he wants. Simple and straight to point.

Comment: @Raxdiam I've updated my answer to explain what's going on, and to provide an alternative version which does the same thing but isn't quite so cryptic.  Hopefully that helps you.  If you have another specific question, you can open a new question to ask it.  You can include a link back to this question or answer if you need to reference it (use the "share" button to get the URL).  Also, be sure to search around StackOverflow for other answers first.  There are tons of questions and answers about parsing JSON; there's a good chance one of them will help you.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like artifacts is an array, so you need to either iterate over them or access via an indexer:

```
foreach (var artifact in builds.artifacts)
{
    var fileName = artifact.fileName;
}
```

or

```
var fileName = builds.artifacts[0].fileName;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, and I don't know enough about this subject to know exactly why.

The only information I can provide is that I get this error:
"Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." within JContainer.cs

Also, for reference, this: http://ci.md-5.net/job/Spigot/api/json?depth=1 is the json document that I am trying to parse. And this site: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ should make it easier to read.

Comment: @Raxdiam - the indexer approach will only work if there is at least one item in the array. The foreach option should always work.

Comment: Well I'm not doubting you or anything. I may just be doing something wrong. And I don't know if I'm using your example correctly either.

Answer (score 0):

Strong typing your convert JSON to C# objects will get you compile time errors. Because you are using the dynamic keyword you will not get compiler errors until you try to run your application.

Create these classes:
[Classes](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/575d06be7a6b645e94e7)

Then modify your current code to be this:

```
var url = "http://ci.md-5.net/job/Spigot/api/json?depth=1";
var content = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);

var responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

Because they are now strong typed you will be able to get compiler errors, to show you that you are doing it wrong. Try to stay away from the dynamic object.

This will now error out because you aren't using it right:

```
foreach (var builds in json.builds)
{
    string fileName = builds.artifacts.fileName;

    lvServers.Items.Add(fileName);
}
```

Your code will now produce an error like this to inform you, it's not right:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UserQuery.Artifact>' does not contain a definition for 'fileName' and no extension method 'fileName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UserQuery.Artifact>' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)
```

If you need to generate future class use the tool [JSON2CSHARP](http://json2csharp.com/). Just know you will need to weed out duplicates though, it is terrible at that.

Comment: The Json is frequently updated on the server that I am pulling it from. This is essential for what I am trying to do with this code. If I go by your example, will I still be able to get what has been newly added?

Comment: You would just have to run the code through the JSON2CSHARP website to update the code. Also it seems I am not sure what to do about the one weird property name you have "origin/master" <--- not sure what to do with that.

But yes if you go this route you have to update the StrongType classes, but if you add properties you will also have to update the dynamic calls so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I updated the Classes I linked to from GistHub removed the massive duplicates. Now when you say your JSON is updated all the time do you mean, that the JSON properties are constanly changing or do you just mean that you are pulling new data all the time?

Because regardless of if the properties are changing you will have to update your C# code regardless.

Comment: An example of it being updated would be, say a new "artifacts" would be written on top of the others, and the oldest one would be removed.

I'm trying to list the first "fileName" value of each artifact, so that the most updated "fileName" would appear at the top of the ListView. In the "builds" schema, there is a property on the same level as "artifacts", which contains the build number. I was planning on combining the "fileName" value with it so tell which build it was. But getting that fileName value is still important.

Comment: I see then I would go with the newly post answer by @Brain Rogers. That seems to be more what you are looking for. You still won't get compile time complains but you will get null references if what you are searching for is missing.